# How can I manage deployed software in a cloud environment?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I can configure an instance in AWS, but I do not understand how to deal with many instances.

Currently, my instance is loaded with mysql, php etc (all in one). However how do I ensure my instances are scaling?  If i have a site that is supposed to be handled using 3 instances and using amazon rds, do I need to host my code base in the 3 instances?

How do people normally do this? Like facebook has 1000+ servers. Do they host their code base in all the 1000+ servers?

Answer (score 0):

Serverfault isn't really the place for "Best practice" questions, but here are a few points:

- Yes you host your PHP codebase on all servers.
- Design a multi-tiered application: web-tier, app-tier (may be combined with web-tier for PHP app), db-tier, storage-tier, etc.
- Leverage the Amazon services for database (RDS), file storage (S3), messaging (SQS), etc. These are the building blocks for your app.
- Prepare a template ("AMI") for each tier and configure CloudWatch to bring them up and down as the load goes up and down over time.
- Do not keep *any* status on the servers, they can come and go at any time.

It's actually quite an art to design a Cloud-aware application and not worth the effort for small apps. In any case it's not something that can be reasonably explained here, too complex a topic.